# Undefined references in imported static library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a 3rd party library, wt_lib.a, that was provided along with the header files. I do know that the CMakeLists used to configure the build for the library includes a target_link_libraries entry with references to R_Lib and T_Lib, which I don't have access to.

I am attempting to build a new application that calls functions within wt_lib.a but am getting undefined reference errors for functions within R_Lib and T_Lib when linking. I have a target_link_libraries entry that includes wt_lib.a but I'm wondering if I also need to link to R_Lib and T_Lib. Since they were previously linked when wt_lib.a was created, I assumed that the it would be ready to go and as long as I linked to that and included the associated headers, I'd have access to that functionality. Is that an incorrect assumption?

I have a CMakeLists.txt to add the library:

```
set(target WTLib)
add_library(${target} SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/wt_lib.a"
)
```

And, in the application CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(target MyApp)
add_executable(${target} ${sources} ${headers} MyAppMain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${target}
  WTLib
)
target_include_directories(${target} PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/WT/include
)
```

Comment: `wt_lib.a` `SHARED` - `.a` is for static libraries, not shared, are you sure it's shared?

Comment: @KamilCuk I had STATIC first but when I copied here, I had SHARED. The results are the same with either

Comment: "... but I'm wondering if I also need to link to R_Lib and T_Lib." - Yes, you need to link also with R_Lib and T_Lib. Since `wt_lib.a` is a **static** library, it cannot be actually linked with other libraries (there is no linking stage when create static libraries).